# The loop with one go-exiftool instance hangs on big amount of files

Tags: go, io, exiftool

I'm looping big ~10k files using go-exiftool.
I'm using one instance of the go-exiftool to get info for all required files.
This code is called 10k times in the loop, where the file is always different.

```
fileInfos := et.ExtractMetadata(file)
```

After the ~7k loops the program hangs. I debugged go-exiftool and found that it hangs in
https://github.com/barasher/go-exiftool/blob/master/exiftool.go#L121
on the line:

```
fmt.Fprintln(io.WriteCloser, "-execute")
```

if i understood correct `io.WriteCloser` has instance of `exec.Command(binary, initArgs...).StdinPipe()`

so, the questions are:

1. Does exec.Command has a limit of execution?
2. If 1) - not, what can be the reason else?
3. Does it depends on the file sizes? I tried another folder and it worked with 35k files and then hanged. How to check that?

**UPDATE:**
i tried to run the same file in 10k loops. Works fine. It looks like it runs out of memory, can it be? I see no problem in the system memory graph. Or stdin is overflowed. Have no idea how to check that.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the underlying exiftool process when this happens (e.g., with strace)? I suspect this is not a problem with Go or go-exiftool, but with the underlying process stopping reading commands from stdin.

Comment: @hmm, thank you for the response. I would assume that it's stopping reading, but it has debug output right after ```fmt.Fprintln(io.WriteCloser, "-execute")``` and this shows that it's stopping on this line. I tried to run with dtruss (for macos). I hope it's a correct tool. I've got pretty big output and in a couple of seconds. Should it work like that? it looks too fast to be true. And what i have to look for there?